# Chapter heading when there is no section

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, sections-paragraphs

I have a chapter where no section appears and in that case I would like to have the chapter as heading.

This is what I tried:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \if@mainmatter
    \markboth{Chapter \thechapter{}: #1}{}%
    \else
    \markboth{Chapter \thechapter{}: #1}{}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately the header at the right side (odd pages) remains without any heading.

How can I fix that?

PS: I can't use fancyhdr package.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `{}` after `\thechapter` because of `:`. Fill in the second argument to `\markboth` with what you want to appear in the header unless countermanded by a `\markright` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like egreg said, you need to specify both arguments for `\markboth`.  I went to the trouble of creating a MWE, so I might as well share it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.~#1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{Chapter \thechapter{}: #1}{Chapter \thechapter{}: #1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{No Section}

\lipsum[1-16]

\chapter{Normal}

\section{Test}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```