# Header not displaying "Appendix A" when using titletoc, only displays A

Tags: header-footer, titletoc, appendix

By using `\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}` I managed to make so that the appendix is displayed as: "Appendix A" and not "A" in the table of content. The problem is that now in my header, it only displays A instead of Appendix A.

It is a bit messy but I try to provide a Minimal Working Example (I am using documentclass report):

```
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{This is my first Appendix} \label{appendix_first}
     \input{Chapters/Appendix A}
\end{appendices}
```

For the header, I use:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L,C]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

The code below, does so that when no chapter is available, it displays the section. Don't think it is that important but included for completness (Taken from this link: [Chapter heading when there is no section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440415/chapter-heading-when-there-is-no-section))

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.~#1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\thechapter{}: #1}{\thechapter{}: #1}%
```

---

So, I looked at this document: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/appendix/appendix.pdf
in (p.3), and it says:
*"header Adds a name (e.g., ‘Appendix’) before each appendix in page headers.
The name is given by the value of `\appendixname`. Note that this is the
default behaviour for classes that have chapters."*

So I think this might be a solution, but I don't know how to implement it.

So, how should I do so that Appendix A is displayed in the header and not just A? Thanks.

Comment: Use `\usepackage[titletoc, header]{appendix}`.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work.

Comment: Could you post  a small, but compete code demonstrating the problem? Maybe there problems with your document class, if it is not  a standard one.

Comment: I second Bernard. Please show a complete, compilable piece of code demonstrating your issue. Also, your interpretation of the redefinition of `\sectionmark` and `\chaptermark` are exactly the opposite of what is intended: that piece of code is so that when there is **no section** within a chapter, the right header is not left empty, but shows also the chapter name. Please clarify whether that is in fact the intended effect, or if you are looking for the opposite effect.

Comment: Also: the `header` option is implemented in the package by redefining the `\sectionmark` command. If your appendices are at chapter level, and has no sections within, then that code is completely inoperative.